# Get object under mouse

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Is there a way to get the current object(s) under the mouse? There's a function called getObjectsUnderPoint() on AS3, but I need to know if AS2 provides a similar functionality. In case it doesn't, anyone has a good implementation of what I am trying to achieve?

Migrating to AS3 is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort of do this in an automated with AS2, but it only gets the top-most object.

This is done using to _droptarget property of movieclips. What you do is make a blank MovieClip, run startDrag on it with the lockCenter arugment set to true. Then you stopDrag and look at that clips _droptarget property.

The only other method of doing this would be to manually loop over your clips and use the hitTest method.

Comment: Seems like iterating is the easier approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

getObjectsUnderPoint returns an Array of objects on an object under the given point.

I wrote this condition to check if the mouse is over any object on a certain layer.

```
if (mySprite.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(mouseX, mouseY)).length) 
{
    return;
}
else
{
    doSomething();
}
```

You could also use stage.getObjectsUnderPoint for a global check.

Hope this helps.

> Migrating to AS3 is not an option.
>   Nevermind...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel, but I'm working on ActionScript 2.